# nest.js can not get the file parameter buffer object when the image is uploaded

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a nest.js to receive the image and upload the image to github, but the buffer attribute of the file is not available, which bothers me
Here is the service code snippet

```
async uploadToGitHub(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    const contentBase64 = file.buffer.toString('base64');
    const fileName = `${new Date().getTime() + extname(file.originalname)}`;
    const filePath = `img/${fileName}`;
    try {
      const response = await this.octokit.repos.createOrUpdateFileContents({
        owner: this.configService.get<string>('GITHUB_OWNER'),
        repo: this.configService.get<string>('GITHUB_REPO'),
        path: filePath,
        message: `Upload image ${fileName}`,
        content: contentBase64,
        branch: this.configService.get<string>('GITHUB_BRANCH'),
      });

      return {
        data: {
          url: response.data.content.download_url,
          fileName,
        },
        message: '上传成功',
      }; // 返回图片的 URL
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error uploading to GitHub');
    }
  }
```

Print log as follows

```
{
fieldname: 'file',
originalname: '扁平铅笔素材.png',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/png',
destination: 'D:\\学习资料\\前端\\项目\\nest-vben-template\\nest\\dist\\images',
filename: '1704718860724.png',
path: 'D:\\学习资料\\前端\\项目\\nest-vben-template\\nest\\dist\\images\\1704718860724.png',
size: 100980
}
\[Nest\] 21752  - 2024/01/08 21:01:00   ERROR \[ExceptionsHandler\] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
```

The controller code snippet is as follows

```
@Controller('upload')
export class UploadController {
constructor(private readonly uploadService: UploadService) {}
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
return this.uploadService.uploadToGitHub(file);
}
}
```

The module code snippet is as follows

```
@Module({
imports: \[MulterModule.register({
storage:diskStorage({
destination:join(\__dirname,"../images"),
filename:(\_,file,callback) =\> {
const fileName = `${new Date().getTime() + extname(file.originalname)}`
return callback(null,fileName)
}
})
// dest: join(\__dirname,"../images"),
})\],
controllers: \[UploadController\],
providers: \[UploadService\]
})
```

I level dish, can not find the problem, hope to get help
Hopefully, we can solve the problem of not getting the buffer in the file